# Get the latest instance of a foreign key in django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Hi I am facing difficulty with a query in Django ORM:

I have two models:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class choices:
    CHOICES = {(0, "Present"),(1, "Absent")}

class Attendance(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                                related_name='attendance')
    date = models.DateField()
    state = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=choices.CHOICES)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I want to get all the students who were present on their respective latest dates of attendance.

Comment: My ultimate aim is to get queryset of students. The queryset with student objects can be in any order, but each student object's latest instance in attendance table needs to be in present state. (I hope that makes sense)

Comment: Can you please explain using some of the fields?

Comment: @ArushSharma what if the student doesn't have any entries in the attendance table?

Comment: for e.g There are 3 students with id 1,2,3. 1 is present on 22/07/2020, absent on 23/07/2020. 2 is absent on 23/07/2020, present on 24/07/2020, 3 is present on 19/07/2020, present on 20/07/2020. So I want to have (2,3) in query set because they were present on the latest date (which are 23/07/2020, 24/07/2020, 20/07/2020 respectively for 1,2,3)

Comment: @lain Shelvington ignore those students.

Comment: @ArushSharma which database are you using?

Comment: @lain Shelvington I am using PostgreSQL, but I guess that shouldn't matter because of ORM.

Comment: @ArushSharma it matters because some databases don't support things like distinct on clauses, luckily PostgreSQL is great and supports it

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution that requires three separate database queries

First get the latest `Attendance` id for each student and get the latest `Attendance` id where the status is present.

```
latest_attendances = Attendance.objects.order_by('student', '-date').distinct('student').values_list('id', flat=True)
latest_present_attendances = latest_attendances.filter(state=0)
```

Using `set` arithmetic we can get all the `Attendance` ids that are common to both (latest and "present")

```
set(latest_attendances) & set(latest_present_attendances)
```

Then pass it to a `Student` query

```
Student.objects.filter(attendance__in=set(latest_attendances) & set(latest_present_attendances))
```